# Strawberry and Netflix?

Tags: slang

I was in en elevator with my girlfriend and a random black guy was in it too, he saw me holding a box of strawberry and ask me "Strawberry and Netflix tonight"? I don't know what he meant, the other white guy in the elevator said "I do that every day".

What does that mean???

Answer (score 1):

It's a variation on the classic '[Netflix and chill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflix_and_chill)' (i.e. have sex), I assume it was apparent you were with your girlfriend.
As you were holding strawberries it became 'strawberries and netflix' instead of 'netflix and chill', perhaps also alluding to all the interesting things you could do with strawberries.

Wikipedia

Comment: How does this explain the bystander's comment?  Also, I am skeptical of this explanation because it was a total stranger making the comment.

Comment: And strangers making sexually oriented remarks never happens? Feel free to provide alternative interpretations :)